# SQL Datetime to select minimum value for a specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

[image]

I need select the min value from a `DateTime` column for specific date - rather the current Date - Today. The database is SQL Server 2012.

Column has employee card swipe data. Every time the card is swiped, an entry is made in `DateTime` column. I want to find the In and Out time. OUT time is easy with `MAX(Datetime)`. But InTime I am not able to select for current day. Some employees have multiple swipes. I want the first swipe for current date.

Any help appreciated.

```
SELECT   
    em.EmployeeCode, em.FirstName, em.LastName,
    (SELECT DISTINCT [aDateTime]
     FROM [Transactions] 
     ORDER BY [aDateTime] DESC
     OFFSET (1) ROWS FETCH NEXT (1) ROWS ONLY) AS InTime,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), MAX(t.aDateTime), 108) AS OutTime, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), MAX(aDateTime), 103) AS Date
FROM
    EmployeeMaster em
INNER JOIN 
    EmployeeFunctionCards ef ON em.EmployeeMasterID = ef.EmployeeMasterID 
INNER JOIN 
     Transactions t ON ef.EmployeeFunctionCardID = t.EmployeeFunctionCardID
WHERE
    t.EventCode = '1' 
GROUP BY
    em.EmployeeCode, em.FirstName, em.LastName
```

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: use min(datetime)

Comment: If you group by date you can get the min and max times for each date the employee has swiped at least once.  Since it is a datetime field you will need to convert to date in the group by clause.

Comment: in out not so easy..... what happens if I clock in at 10:00PM and clock out at 4AM the next day....  Sample data expected results would help clarify this question.   or what happens if I clock in at 8:00AM and clock in at 8:00AM the next day with no clock out....  so now it seems like i've been there 24 hours right?  If the rule is by day, then I guess we could use min/max `group by employee,date` right?

Comment: I have added the Query and the Output. Th InTime is showin wrong Data. Can someone please correct my query? So my InTime values are correct.

Comment: There should be some flag to identify whether the swipe is IN or OUT right? Can you please give me complete table structure?

Comment: Rajesh, No there is not a flag to identify which is in/out. So my logic was the min value is In and Max is Out. They are ok with it.